# Angular 5 Animations: Custom (not linear) animation-timing-function for keyframes

Tags: angular, animation

The requirements is to create an animation with a custom timing funnction. It can be defined via css as follows:

```
animation: text-animation 10s steps(50) 1s 1 normal both;

@keyframes text-animation {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50em;
  }
}
```

The same animation can be presented as follows for the linear animation function

```
animations: [
    trigger("textAnimation", [
      transition(":enter", [
        query(":self", [
          animate(
            "10s",
            keyframes([
              style({
                width: "0",
              }),
              style({
                width: "50em",
              })
            ])
          )
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Changing above function to something like

```
animate(
  "10s steps(50) 1s 1 normal both",
  keyframes([
    style({
      width: "0",
    }),
    style({
      width: "50em",
    })
  ])
)
```

Doesn't bear any fruits, except an error **"The provided timing value is invalid"**.

Comment: Well keep the official syntax and it will work ...

Comment: 2trichetriche. What do you mean?

Comment: There's [**documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/animations#multi-step-animations-with-keyframes) and you should follow it.

Comment: All for linear animation though. As I said it works flawlessly. I need stepped (animation function) one.

Comment: And as written, you can use `offset` to step your animation.

Comment: Ofsetting 50 times?

Comment: This is an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: `offset: 'steps(50)'`

Comment: I'll try, but I don't think it's the case. From my understanding it reprenets keyframes timing distribution only

Comment: Well I sure won't try it for you ! Unless you provide a [mcve] of course. And if it doesn't work, consider asking directly on Angular's repository.